# How to hide a part of my Qcircuit?

Tags: qcircuit

With the help of `qcircuit.tex` ([official main page](http://physics.unm.edu/CQuIC/Qcircuit/)) I created the representation of a quantum circuit. I now want to hide some parts of the circuit, just like `\phantom{}` would do (but it seems like I can't use `\phantom{}` inside the `qcircuit` environment).

Below is the graphical representation of my circuit (MWE at the end):

[image]

I tried to draw a white rectangle above the part I wanted to hide with TikZ, but after a long fight against box sizes, I could not find a way to superpose nicely a white TikZ rectangle over my circuit.

Example of result I would like to have:
[image]

Minimal Working Example (needs [qcircuit.tex](http://physics.unm.edu/CQuIC/Qcircuit/Qcircuit.tex) and graphicx):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}                 % Many thing (scalebox)
\usepackage{qcircuit}                 % Draw quantum circuits

\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{\left\vert #1 \right\rangle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \leavevmode
  \resizebox{.95\linewidth}{!}{
    \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=2em {
      \lstick{\ket{0}}    & \qw  & \qw      & \qw & \qw      & \qw               & \qw                                                & \gate{R_y(\lambda^{-1})} & \qw                                        & \qw              & \qw      & \meter & \rstick{\ket{1}} \cw \\
      \lstick{\ket{0}^m}  & \qw  & {/^m}\qw & \qw & \gate{H} & \ctrl{1}          & \gate{\mathcal{Q}\mathcal{F}\mathcal{T}_m^\dagger} & \ctrl{-1}                & \gate{\mathcal{Q}\mathcal{F}\mathcal{T}_m} & \ctrl{1}         & \gate{H} & \qw    & \rstick{\ket{0}^m} \qw \\
      \lstick{\ket{b}}    & \qw  & {/^n}\qw & \qw & \qw      & \gate{e^{-iAt_0}} & \qw                                                & \qw                      & \qw                                        & \gate{e^{iAt_0}} & \qw      & \qw    & \rstick{\ket{x}} \qw \\
    }
  }
  \caption{Starting point for HHL algorithm}
  \label{fig:hhl1}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `\clipbox` from the `trimclip` package, which is part of the `adjustbox` package bundle.

In the example below there are two variants: one without the floating `figure` environment (using `\captionof` from the `caption` package for the caption), which is aligned left, and one with the floating environment, which is centered. Note that I removed the `leavevmode` line.

The `\clipbox` command can be used in different ways. In this example the version with four arguments is used, indicating the amount of clipping left, bottom, right, top. Note that there is a bit of negative clip on the left, for some reason a bit of the figure was clipped when providing `0pt`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}                 % Many thing (scalebox)
\usepackage{qcircuit}                 % Draw quantum circuits
\usepackage{trimclip}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{\left\vert #1 \right\rangle}}
\newcommand{\hhlcircuit}{\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=2em {
      \lstick{\ket{0}}    & \qw  & \qw      & \qw & \qw      & \qw               & \qw                                                & \gate{R_y(\lambda^{-1})} & \qw                                        & \qw              & \qw      & \meter & \rstick{\ket{1}} \cw \\
      \lstick{\ket{0}^m}  & \qw  & {/^m}\qw & \qw & \gate{H} & \ctrl{1}          & \gate{\mathcal{Q}\mathcal{F}\mathcal{T}_m^\dagger} & \ctrl{-1}                & \gate{\mathcal{Q}\mathcal{F}\mathcal{T}_m} & \ctrl{1}         & \gate{H} & \qw    & \rstick{\ket{0}^m} \qw \\
      \lstick{\ket{b}}    & \qw  & {/^n}\qw & \qw & \qw      & \gate{e^{-iAt_0}} & \qw                                                & \qw                      & \qw                                        & \gate{e^{iAt_0}} & \qw      & \qw    & \rstick{\ket{x}} \qw \\
    }}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \clipbox{-20pt 0pt 238pt 0pt}{% 
  \resizebox{.95\linewidth}{!}{\hhlcircuit}%
  }
  \captionof{figure}{Starting point for HHL algorithm}


\begin{figure}[h]
  \clipbox{-20pt 0pt 238pt 0pt}{% 
  \resizebox{.95\linewidth}{!}{\hhlcircuit}%
  }
  \caption{Starting point for HHL algorithm}
  \label{fig:hhl2}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I will try that tomorrow! Thanks for the quick (and nice!) answer ;)